# How to find allocated (independent) memory section from another process?

Tags: c#, memory

I mean how To find a section was allocated by another program in another process fastly, and it's size is (8 Bytes) so when i use this code :

```
public static uint FindSignature(IntPtr hProcess, byte[] sigBuffer)
    {
        byte[] lpBuffer = new byte[524288];
        uint lpNumberOfBytesRead = 0;
        uint CurAddr = 0x00000000;
        bool Result = false;

        Result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, CurAddr, lpBuffer, 524288, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        while (CurAddr + 524288 <= 0x7FFFFFFF)
        {
            if (Result != false)
            {
                int Index = ByteSearch(lpBuffer, sigBuffer);
                if (Index != -1)
                {
                    return (uint)(CurAddr + Index);
                }
            }
            CurAddr += (uint)(524288 - sigBuffer.Length);
            Result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, CurAddr, lpBuffer, 524288, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I can't find it because i read 512 KB at the same time so it returns false.

And thanks.

Comment: I think if anyone can get memory map of a process like ollydbg.
it would be very helpful

Comment: You may find the [VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) API function useful for this task.